# Ruby on Rails dynamic form content return to controller

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails form which contains a table described below:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'recipes', :action => 'attempt_create') do %>

    <table>

        <tr class="ingredients">

            <td><%= label_tag(:ingredient) %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:ingredient_count) %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:ingredient_unit) %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag(:ingredient_name) %></td>
            <td><%= submit_tag "Add Ingredient", :id => 'ingredient', :type => 'button' %></td>

        </tr>

        <tr class="submit">

             <td>&nbsp;</td>
             <td><%= submit_tag("Create") %></td>

        </tr>

    </table>

<% end %>
```

There is a button, which triggers jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ingredient").click(function() {

        var count = $("#ingredient_count").val();
        var unit = $("#ingredient_unit").val();
        var name = $("#ingredient_name").val();

        if((count != '') && (name != '') && (unit != '')) {

          $(".ingredients").append("<td><p>" + count + " " + unit + " of " + name + "</td></p>");

          $("#ingredient_count").val('');
          $("#ingredient_unit").val('');
          $("#ingredient_name").val('');
      }
  });
});
```

This function dynamically generates HTML content. This content are a ingredients for recipe.

My question is **How to get all the data back from view to recipes_controller.rb method attempt_create?**

I need to save the data from the form to database when the form is submitted. That mean, when I save whole recipe, I need to retrieve and save all its ingredients.

Comment: By submitting the form

Comment: Yes, but how to retrieve the data generated by jQuery back to controller.

Comment: You can use ``remote: true`` in the form so that form will be submitted in js format and in js.erb file you just append the result to the target.

Comment: Once you will submit the form, you can see logs in the log file. From there you will get idea how rails send data.. try that

Comment: @ProsenjitSaha can you explain me more?

Comment: following ans is enough or do i need to explain it more?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Logs doesn't show my dynamically generated HTML content...

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your Gemfile.

Add `resources: recipes` to your routes file

Add the following code to recipes_controller

```
def index
  @recipes = Recipes.all
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
  if @recipe.save
    render layout: false if request.xhr?
  else
    render :index
  end
end
```

Now in index.html.erb file add the form content

```
<table>
  <tbody class="ingredients">
    <%= render @recipes %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= form_for Recipe.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :ingredient_count, placeholder: "Ingredient Count" %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :ingredient_unit, placeholder: "Ingredient Unit" %><br/>
  <%= f.text_field :ingredient_name, placeholder: "Ingredient Name" %><br/>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Add a new file named `_recipe.html.erb` under recipes folder and add the following code:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= recipe.ingredient_count %></td>
  <td><%= recipe.ingredient_unit %></td>
  <td><%= recipe.ingredient_name %></td>
</tr>
```

Now add a new file named `create.js.erb` under the recipes directory and add the following code:

```
$(".ingredients").append("<%= j(render @recipe) %>");
```

Comment: Sorry, Im new in Rails, I need more explanation.

Comment: What does `remote: true`. Also I see .js.erb for the first time. Why do I need this?

Comment: Basically when you submit the form or click on link it will send a html request and redirect to new page or render the whole page, but if you add ``remote: true`` it will send the js request and to handle the js request you need js.erb file. By using the js.erb file you can just update the portion of html without rendering the whole page again.

Comment: Thats what Im already doing, isn't it? What is the difference?

Comment: No you are not doing right. You have to save the record first and then append the record to html. If there is any error you will still add the record to html which is not right approach.

Comment: you have to save the record in controller

Comment: yes you have to use one instance variable and access the variable in js.erb file

Comment: I have updated my ans. Hope you will get what you asking for. If there is any issue let me know. Thanks